# Exercise on linear maps with a nilpotent one

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, nilpotence

sorry for asking to help me with this trivial problem. Unfortunately I'm in a very bad shape with linear algebra, being this the fourth exercise I'm not able to solve.
I need some suggestion.

$f,g:V\to V$ linear maps, with $f$ being nilpotent and

$fg-gf=f$

Prove that $\ker(f)$ is invariant for $g$.

I think I have to prove that $g(\ker(f))\subseteq\ker(f)$.
I know that if $f$ is nilpotent, then there exists a $k>1$ for which $f^k=0$, and, moreover $f$ has the only eigenvalue $\lambda=0$.

This problem shouldn't be hard to solve. In your opinion, what do I have to revise to learn making this exercises? Maybe I should start with something simpler?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are preparing these exercises for some course and you have trouble with the theoretical ones like this, then you could try (re)proving some basic theorems from your book/notes, peeking at the proof if you get stuck for more than, say 10/15 minutes. This should help you get a feeling of the techniques you'll need.

Comment: The equation $fg-gf=f$ implies already that $f$ is nilpotent. So we don't need this assumption.

Comment: @DietrichBurde this is an interesting observation.  Is there a quick proof of this implication?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, see Proposition $2.2$ [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_20_matrix_equ.pdf).

Comment: @DietrichBurde that's a neat proof!  Thanks.

Comment: This problem is from an old test of my school. I think that knowing or proving that implication was not in the scope of the test. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be an element of $\ker(f)$. Then
$$
0 = f(x) = (fg - gf)(x)
$$
implies (by linearity)
$$
f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = g(0) = 0
$$
i.e. $g(x) \in \ker(f)$. Since the choice of $x$ was arbitrary, this implies that $g(\ker(f)) \subseteq \ker(f)$.

---

All you need to know to solve this is what the kernel of a linear map is and that a linear map always sends $0$ to $0$. Then you observe that $f$ and $g$ commute (i.e. $f \circ g = g \circ f$) on $\ker(f)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have no clue. As you can see, it can be proved even without that assumption...

Comment: Ahah, I swear, I solved exercises a little more difficult than this. Maybe today was not a good day to play with algebra. There are two more question about this problem, you all mind if tomorrow I ask here or (I hope) I write how I do? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped you, be sure to accept it (by clicking the "v" next to the vote arrows). You can ask how many questions you like here, as long as they make sense and are well formatted.